# Найти строку с максимальным значением в каждой группе

Tags: python, база-данных, pandas, group-by

Есть exel таблица, в ней в одном столбце перечислен список городов, в другом годов, в третьем номера недель, в четвертом количество человек и ещё несколько столбцов которые можно опустить. Нужно найти неделю, при которой wd_total является максимальной а wda_total имеет значение Э, то есть нужно выбирать максимальные значения из Э, только сделать нужно для городов и годов отдельно, при этом  порядковый номер недели считался не от начала года, а от появления первой буквы Э в массиве данных. то есть например для Архангельска 1990г это неделя 4, а для Архангельска 1991г неделя 3, так как из всех Э за этот период, максимальное значение приходится на третью Э?

https://yadi.sk/i/dkGsdWKdH7NC0w

Comment: Если чисто excel - то сводная таблица - несколько кликов- результат. Питон - прийдется писать код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel(r'D:\download\табл1.xlsx', na_values=['NULL'])

def f(d):
    idx_max = np.argmax(d['wd_total'].values) + 1
    return d.nlargest(1, ['wd_total']).assign(week=idx_max)

res = (df[df['wda_total']=='Э'].groupby(['town_name','cld_year'], as_index=False)
         .apply(lambda x: f(x))
         .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
```

результат (обратите внимание на последний столбец `week`):

```
In [105]: res
     ...:
Out[105]:
         town_name  cld_year  week_number  wd_total wda_total  qty_total  wd_0_2 ...  wd_7_14  wda_7_14  qty_7_14   wd_15  wda_15    qty_15 week
3      Архангельск      1990            4    8357.0         Э   424700.0   725.0 ...   1427.0         Э   48865.0  4637.0       Э  333581.0    4
60     Архангельск      1991            9   10206.0         Э   427600.0   694.0 ...   3239.0         Э   49377.0  4621.0       Э  337173.0    3
107    Архангельск      1992            4    9067.0         Э   428200.0   673.0 ...   2696.0         Э   49168.0  3886.0       Э  339615.0    3
162    Архангельск      1993            7    6578.0         Э   421000.0   391.0 ...   1620.0         Э   49188.0  3434.0       Э  334924.0    3
214    Архангельск      1994            7    8026.0         Э   417000.0   487.0 ...   1858.0         Э   49002.0  4600.0       Э  334077.0    3
311    Архангельск      1995           52    9849.0         Э   414700.0   546.0 ...   3276.0         Э   50194.0  4912.0       Э  333036.0   10
313    Архангельск      1996            1    5229.0         Э   382600.0   434.0 ...   1127.0         Э   51160.0  2822.0       Э  302290.0    1
369    Архангельск      1997            5    6813.0         Э   379900.0   408.0 ...   2373.0         Э   51200.0  3386.0       Э  301768.0    4
428    Архангельск      1998           12    8429.0         Э   372000.0   420.0 ...   3242.0         Э   50116.0  3743.0       Э  296618.0    3
476    Архангельск      1999            8   11964.0         Э   372500.0   643.0 ...   2934.0         Э   48512.0  7476.0       Э  299877.0    4
...            ...       ...          ...       ...       ...        ...     ... ...      ...       ...       ...     ...     ...       ...  ...
68273       Якутск      2003           12    3708.0         Э   232730.0   685.0 ...   1247.0         Э   27473.0   903.0       Э  184374.0    6
68315       Якутск      2004            2    2264.0         Э   235290.0   645.0 ...    324.0       NaN   26387.0   779.0       Э  187409.0    2
68380       Якутск      2005           15    2040.0         Э   252107.0   543.0 ...    398.0         Э   30731.0   544.0       Э  197922.0    6
68430       Якутск      2006           13    2213.0         Э   258992.0   554.0 ...    441.0         Э   30450.0   641.0       Э  202730.0    2
68619       Якутск      2009           45   11807.0         Э   276245.0  2131.0 ...   2834.0         Э   30702.0  3887.0       Э  216846.0    5
68686       Якутск      2011            8    4116.0         Э   287954.0  1099.0 ...    380.0       NaN   30843.0  1654.0       Э  224807.0    4
68745       Якутск      2012           15    3297.0         Э   295664.0  1038.0 ...    542.0         Э   31244.0   551.0     NaN  232277.0    3
68799       Якутск      2013           16    3409.0         Э   312596.0  1304.0 ...    523.0         Э   29467.0   343.0     NaN  249632.0    3
68894       Якутск      2015            7    3995.0         Э   325241.0  1381.0 ...    795.0         Э   31414.0   481.0     NaN  257818.0    2
68944       Якутск      2016            5    6424.0         Э   325241.0  1653.0 ...    719.0         Э   31414.0  1966.0       Э  257818.0    2

[972 rows x 19 columns]
```